# IvyDE unable to resolve Mule dependencies

Tags: java, maven, ant, mule, ivyde

I am working with Apache Ivy to manage transitive dependencies.

Working with Maven was quite a good experience because if there was any dependency that was not available at a remote directory or available with a different version, then Maven would manage those effectively.

However, Ivy gets stuck with this in my case as I am trying to manage Mule dependencies but it is being difficult for Ivy to manage while Maven manages it well without any problems.

One more important point is that I cannot even exclude any dependency because I don't want to exclude but I want Ivy to be capable enough so that it can manage it all or any other way if any.

Below is a screenshot of the error along with the necessary XML files.

[image]

**ivy.xml**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
<info
    organisation="MyOrganization"
    module="TestForIvySupport"
    status="integration">
</info>

<dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.mule" name="mule-core" rev="3.6.0"/>       
</dependencies>
```

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<settings defaultResolver="chained"/>
<resolvers>
    <chain name="chained">
            <url name="custom-repo">
            <ivy pattern="https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
            <artifact pattern="https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
            </url>
        <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true" root="http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/"/>
        <ibiblio name="ibiblio1" m2compatible="true" root="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"/>
   </chain>
</resolvers>
```

**build.xml**

```
<project name="test ivy" default="test" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
<target name="test" description="Test ivy installation">
<ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="false" pattern="myfolder/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Are you using an ivysettings file? The groupid "org.mule.extensions" does not exist in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.mule.extensions%22

Comment: Hello Mark, I am not using any ivysettings file till now. but if, Maven handles all those dependency itself then why Ivy is not handling that including the mule dependencies.

Comment: Check the link I included. The dependency does not exist in Maven Central, which explains why ivy failed. That was why I asked whether you were using an ivysettings file. I was speculating that perhaps you were downloading from an alternative Maven repository.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have updated the question please go through it once again as I am still struggling with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example I had a different error:

```
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.mule.mvel#mule-mvel2;2.1.9-MULE-005: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.mule.common#mule-common;3.6.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I eventually got it working but discovered a broken POM.

## Working Example

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
  <info
    organisation="MyOrganization"
    module="TestForIvySupport"
    status="integration">
  </info>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Exclude the broken dependency -->
    <dependency org="org.mule" name="mule-core" rev="3.6.0" conf="default">       
      <exclude org="com.github.stephenc.eaio-grabbag" module="grabbag"/>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Just pull down the jar artifact associated with the module -->
    <dependency org="com.github.stephenc.eaio-grabbag" name="grabbag" rev="1.8.1" conf="default">       
      <artifact name="grabbag" type="jar"/>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Notes:

- The POM associated with the grabbag dependency is broken.
- Work-around tells ivy to ignore the POM and then we explicitly pull down the jar file as a second dependency declaration.

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="chained"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chained" returnFirst="true">
      <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="mulesoft" m2compatible="true" root="https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- Simplified the settings file to use ibiblio resources to talk to just two Maven repositories: Maven Central and the Mulesoft repository

## Error analysis

### Analysis of first error

I tracked this down to a problem with the parent pom of the "mule-core" module.

- http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.mule|mule|3.6.0|pom

There is an override dependency where the property refers to a version of "mule-mvel2" module that doesn't exist in Maven Central

```
<properties>
  ..
  <muleMvelVersion>2.1.9-MULE-005</muleMvelVersion>
  ..
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.mvel</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-mvel2</artifactId>
  <version>${muleMvelVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Managed to fix this by adding the following Mulesoft repository.

- https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus

### Analysis of second error

Trouble shooting this further I discovered a second cascaded error:

```
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[ivy:resolve]       :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.github.stephenc.eaio-grabbag#grabbag;1.8.1!grabbag.non-maven-jar
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

This problem is more serious as it's caused by a misconfigured POM file:

- http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.github.stephenc.eaio-grabbag|grabbag|1.8.1|pom

Where the packaging has been changed from the "jar" default

```
<packaging>non-maven-jar</packaging>
```

The ivy work-around for is to exclude this broken transitive dependency and then explicitly pull down the jar artifact as a second dependency in the ivy file.

I have raised a [github issue](https://github.com/stephenc/eaio-grabbag/issues/1) with the the project.